# Was Jerome K Jerome Vice President of the Oxford University Labour party?

Tags: united-kingdom

In his autobiography, My Life and Times (page 102), Jerome said

> I was a die-hard Tory at twenty-five... Now I am a Vice-President, I believe, of the Oxford University Labour Party.

He says 'I believe' which is odd. His autobiography was published in 1926. Was there a University of Oxford Labour Party before 1926, and did Jerome hold any position in it, honorary or otherwise? He was never a student at Oxford, as far as I can tell.

I haven't read the book, it was quoted in an answer to [another question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/8362/was-jerome-k-jerome-politically-active).

Answer (score 4):

**Jerome Klapka Jerome** (1859-1927)

An entry on him in the Oxford Dictionary of National Biography by Damian Atkinson, makes no mention whatever of Oxford University, nor is there any of the Labour Party, nor indication that he was interested in politics.

His parents both died when he was in his early teens and he led a penurious existence for much of his life, having left school at fourteen. Too old for the British Army he was an ambulance driver in the French Army in the first world war.

Atkinson mentions Jerome's 1926 autobiography, but says nothing about any membership of the Labour Party. He was honoured with the freedom of Walsall, just before his death in 1927, and The Oxford University Labour Club certainly existed at the time, having been founded in 1919.

Jerome clearly had connections with Oxforshire as that is where his ashes were interred - St Mary's Church, Ewelme.

So while it is conceivable that he could have become a member of the Labour Party later in life, his biographer makes no reference to it.